# Problems with android activity and query to MySQL server with Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview, android-volley

This is the problem:
When I try to make a query to the DB by a php page, the result of the query didn't "arrive" to the smartphone.

```
setPartenza(tBoxPartenza.getText().toString());
setArrivo(tBoxArrivo.getText().toString());

final String KEY_FERM1 = "ferm_1";
final String KEY_FERM2 = "ferm_2";
String url = "<url>";
String ferm_1, ferm_2, jsonresp;
String result = null;



StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            }) {
                  @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put(KEY_FERM1, getPartenza());
                            params.put(KEY_FERM2, getArrivo());
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                    queue.add(stringRequest);

if (result != null) {
      RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
      MainRecyclerAdapter adapter = null;
      try {
            adapter = new MainRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
      recyclerView.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter));
} else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "result == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When the system execute this, in the recycler will not appear nothing, bcause the result variable equal nothing, well I don't know if volley get the lock until the query arrive and also I'm SURE of the result of the php page, but I don't know where I wrong, any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after hour of coding I found the solution, I put the method to display all data on the recycler inside the method "onResponse" by this way the method get the lock and until the response is not null, it waits... after that it displays everithing on the recycler

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a bunch of data for recyclerview use jsonArray type of data from php and use JsonArrayRequest